# Python 2.7 32-bit install on Win 7: No registry keys?

Tags: python, windows, registry, installation

I have downloaded the Python 2.7.2 Windows x86 32-bit MSI from python.org and installed it on a 64-bit Windows 7 system.  Everything works (at least the command-line interpreter starts and runs), but the install process does not create any `Python` entries under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE in the Windows registry.

Various blogs refer to problems created by *incomplete* Python registry entries when attempting to configure third-party libraries, but I have not found a description of the complete *absence* of a Python entry in the registry.

I plan to use Python only with the Google Apps Engine SDK and (hopefully) django-nonrel for some fairly simple Google Apps projects.  The absence of a Python registry key may not even be an issue for me, but the Django setup docs assume its existence and suggest adding path information to it as a way to populate Python's `sys.path` list.

Anyone else run into this?  Is an additional install step necessary to create the key?  Should I manually create it using `regedit`?  Is it even needed, or can the PATH and/or PYTHONPATH environment variables be used for everything instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

32-bit applications installed on 64-bit OSes store their registry values in: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node. If you look there, you should see the settings you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you!  I saw that registry node mentioned in a couple blogs but hadn't looked there on my system.