# Is it possible to use 32 bit ctypes with a 64 bit Python interpreter?

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

If not, can I install both versions of python on my system? How do I differentiate between them?

Comment: Update the tags to include windows.

Comment: @tMC: done - also fixed the title

Comment: To install both versions of python on windows just run the msi windows installer and change the path name. So install one with "C:\PythonXX" and the other "C:\PythonXX64" Whenever you run python you will have to call C:\PythonXX\python.exe or just add the C:\PythonXX folder to you environmental variable path.

Answer (score 3):

On windows the python installer does **not** add the interpreter to the path by default, or set up any entries in the registry. So, just run the 32 bit installer, then run the 64 bit installer and set it to install to a different location.

Then you can create a shortcut to each interpreter in `c:\windows` (which is on your path). Name one shortcut `python` and the other `python64` and you should be *mostly* good.

You will also probably want to look into using [virtualenv](http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip/) for keeping everything separate on projects.

Comment: It does not answer the question, Python's installer does create entries in the registry (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289859/) and users should not create any shortcuts in the %SYSTEMROOT% directory.

Comment: I've found pyvenv a lot easier to use on windows if you are using Python 3.4.